# [rosbag] Synchronisation between camera_info and image

Tags: ros, rosbag, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

Quick question: My setup is Kinect => Depth Image => MoveIt =>Octomap

I want to record what's happening in the real world and to be able to replay it later on, so that the same octomap appears again. My idea was to record the depth image via rosbag and replay it later. Therefore I recorded `/camera/depth/image_raw` and `/camera/depth/camera_info`.

Now when I replay these topics to MoveIt, it complains like this:

```
[ WARN] [1411464286.696762717]: [image_transport] Topics '/camera_top/depth/image_raw' and '/camera_top/depth/camera_info' do not appear to be synchronized. In the last 10s:
    Image messages received:      69
    CameraInfo messages received: 237
    Synchronized pairs:           0
```

How would I achieve such synchronisation?

Thanks in advance,

Rabe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193293/%5Brosbag%5D-synchronisation-between-camera_info-and-image/) by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 683 on 2014-09-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2014-09-23**:
It sounds like you problem might be different, but are you using use_sim_time and --clock with rosbag play?  http://wiki.ros.org/Clock   I think even if you aren't because CameraInfo and Image both have embedded timestamps they should still appear synchronized.  Do the messages look good in rqt_bag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was, that I recorded the messages over a distributed system. Thanks to lucasw I opened the bag file in rqt_bags and saw that they indeed where not synchronised...

After rerecording them in one place, everything worked fine (or at least the next error appeared, but this one is unrelated :D MoveIt seems to have some issues with simulated time...)

---

Originally posted by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) with karma: 683 on 2014-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0